# How can I find the current users primary key to check if it matches a notes pk?

Tags: python, django, primary-key

I am working on an application that stores data on different artists, venues, and notes the user can create for shows. I am currently trying to implement a feature to delete an existing note based off it's PK and the users PK associated with that note. I have most the work done but I don't know how they are storing the current logged in users PK to check before deleting.

Here is what I have so far and links for reference:

https://github.com/claraj/lmn/blob/master/lmn/views/views_notes.py

```
# Note related paths
path('notes/latest/', views_notes.latest_notes, name='latest_notes'),
path('notes/detail/<int:note_pk>/', views_notes.note_detail, name='note_detail'),
path('notes/for_show/<int:show_pk>/', views_notes.notes_for_show, name='notes_for_show'),
path('notes/add/<int:show_pk>/', views_notes.new_note, name='new_note'),
path('notes/detail/<int:show_pk>/delete', views_notes.delete_note, name='delete_note'),
```

https://github.com/claraj/lmn/blob/master/lmn/urls.py

```
# Delete note for show
@login_required
def delete_note(request, show_pk): 

# I need to grab the existing note PK and user PK associated with that note
# Then check if the current user matches the PK associated with that note to delete or return a 403 status code.
if note.user == request.user:
    note.delete()
    return redirect('latest_notes')
else:
    return HttpResponseForbidden
```

https://github.com/claraj/lmn/blob/master/lmn/templates/lmn/notes/note_list.html

```
# Grabs PK for specific note
<form action="{% url 'delete_note' note.pk %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="delete">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove a `note` or a `show`? If it is a note, why do you use `show_pk` as parameter name?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I was thinking I might need it to find the specific show a note is tied to. I figured it out though just by using note_pk with this - note = get_object_or_404(Note, pk=note_pk)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the filtering in a single `.delete()` query:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

# Delete note for show
@login_required
def delete_note(request, show_pk): 
    dels, __ = Note.objects.filter(
        pk=show_pk,
        user=request.user
    ).delete()
    if dels:
        return return redirect('latest_notes')
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

A GET request however is not supposed to change entities. Only requests like POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, etc. are. Therefore you might want to restrict this to only POST requests:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

# Delete note for show
@login_required
@require_http_methods(['POST', 'DELETE'])
def delete_note(request, show_pk): 
    dels, __ = Note.objects.filter(
        pk=show_pk,
        user=request.user
    ).delete()
    if dels:
        return return redirect('latest_notes')
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```